# Unable to read .nc file using netCDF4 in python

Tags: python, netcdf

```py
import netCDF4 as nc

data=nc.Dataset('oisst-avhrr-v02r01.20100308.nc')
```

​

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-5387b338d47c> in <module>
      1 import netCDF4 as nc
----> 2 data=nc.Dataset('oisst-avhrr-v02r01.20100308.nc')

netCDF4\_netCDF4.pyx in netCDF4._netCDF4.Dataset.__init__()

netCDF4\_netCDF4.pyx in netCDF4._netCDF4._ensure_nc_success()


OSError: [Errno -51] NetCDF: Unknown file format: b'oisst-avhrr-v02r01.20100308.nc'
```

Comment: Can you post the file somewhere that others can try to open it?

Comment: Thanks @DopplerShift . I have checked this. The problem is that file itself is corrupted. Actually corrupted files were being downloaded when I used webscraping.